# how can i fix entropy yielding nan?

Tags: python, numpy, entropy

I am trying to calculate entropy from array resulted from np.histogram by

```
mu1, sigma1 = 0, 1
s1 = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 100000)
hist1 = np.histogram(s1, bins=100, range=(-20,20), density=True)
data1 = hist1[0]
ent1 = -(data1*np.log(np.abs(data1))).sum()
```

However, this ent1 would return nan. What is the problem here?

Comment: `data1` have zero values inside it and Log(0) is not defined, therefore it returns nan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have zero probabilities in your histogram, which don't make numerical sense when applying Shannon's entropy formula. A solution is to ignore the zero probabilities.

```
mu1, sigma1 = 0, 1
s1 = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 100000)
hist1 = np.histogram(s1, bins=100, range=(-20,20), density=True)
data1 = hist1[0]
non_zero_data = data1[data1 != 0]
ent1 = -(non_zero_data*np.log(np.abs(non_zero_data))).sum()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally got it going. : ) I also tried using spicy.stats.entropy but I see that the values are different though? despite the same formula?

Comment: No worries. Take care when using `spicy.stats.entropy` because it normalizes the values, for element-wise entropy use `scipy.special.entr` as @watten-weckesser explained.

Comment: @MateusZitelli Actually zero probabilities DO make sense for Shannons entropy, but you have to interpret `0*log(0)` as zero. This makes sense since the limit as `p` goes to zero of `p*log(p)` is zero, which is about the only sensible way of interpreting `0*log(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

To compute the entropy, you could use [`scipy.special.entr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.entr.html).  For example,

```
In [147]: from scipy.special import entr

In [148]: x = np.array([3, 2, 1, 0, 0.5, 2.5, 5])

In [149]: entr(x).sum()
Out[149]: -14.673474028700136
```

To check that result, we can also compute the entropy using [`scipy.special.xlogy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.xlogy.html):

```
In [150]: from scipy.special import xlogy

In [151]: -xlogy(x, x).sum()
Out[151]: -14.673474028700136
```

Finally, we can verify that is the same result that you expect:

```
In [152]: xnz = x[x != 0]

In [153]: -(xnz*np.log(xnz)).sum()
Out[153]: -14.673474028700136
```

Answer (score 0):

use `numpy.nansum`

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html

```
mu1, sigma1 = 0, 1
s1 = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 100000)
hist1 = np.histogram(s1, bins=100, range=(-20,20), density=True)
data1 = hist1[0]
ent1 = -np.nansum(data1*np.log(np.abs(data1)))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30513067)